# Blackberry widget that does reverse geocoding to a street address?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Can anyone kindly show an example or two so that I can have some clarity. I need to have an application developed that can get current GPS location and reverse geocode the address.  I have googled this and have not been able to come up with a solution.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a search for 'blackberry location geocoding' and the first link was for BlackBerry documentation: [Geocoding and reverse geocoding](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/Geocode_service_overview_865662_11.jsp)

> The [net.rim.device.api.lbs.Locator](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/Locator.html) API provides the geocoding methods that can allow you to request geospatial coordinates for a street address. It also provides the reverse geocoding methods that can allow you to request a street address for a geospatial coordinate.

RIM even provides a guide for doing reverse geocoding:
[Retrieve an address by using reverse geocoding](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/Reverse_geocode_API_example_869857_11.jsp)